# Algorithm: Check It two polygon intersect is not working for some points

Tags: wordpress, algorithm, polygon

I found this algorithm to check if two polygons intersect:

https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/determine-if-two-polygons-overlap/#comment-6287

```
//poly1 and poly2 are arrays of VELatlongs that represent polygons
function ArePolygonsOverlapped(poly1, poly2)
{
    if(poly1.length >= 3 && poly2.length >= 3)
    {
        //close polygons
        poly1.push(poly1[0]);
        poly2.push(poly2[0]);

        for(var i = 0; i < poly1.length-1;i++)
        {
            for(var k = 0; k < poly2.length-1; k++)
            {
    if(SimplePolylineIntersection(poly1[i],poly1[i+1],poly2[k],poly2[k+1])!=null)
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    return null;
}


function SimplePolylineIntersection(latlong1,latlong2,latlong3,latlong4)
{
    //Line segment 1 (p1, p2)
    var A1 = latlong2.Latitude - latlong1.Latitude;
    var B1 = latlong1.Longitude - latlong2.Longitude;
    var C1 = A1*latlong1.Longitude + B1*latlong1.Latitude;

    //Line segment 2 (p3,  p4)
    var A2 = latlong4.Latitude - latlong3.Latitude;
    var B2 = latlong3.Longitude - latlong4.Longitude;
    var C2 = A2*latlong3.Longitude + B2*latlong3.Latitude;

    var determinate = A1*B2 - A2*B1;

    var intersection;
    if(determinate != 0)
    {
        var x = (B2*C1 - B1*C2)/determinate;
        var y = (A1*C2 - A2*C1)/determinate;

        var intersect = new VELatLong(y,x);

        if(inBoundedBox(latlong1, latlong2, intersect) && 
inBoundedBox(latlong3, latlong4, intersect))
            intersection = intersect;
        else
            intersection = null;
    }
    else //lines are parrallel
        intersection = null; 

    return intersection;
}

//latlong1 and latlong2 represent two coordinates that make up the bounded box
//latlong3 is a point that we are checking to see is inside the box
function inBoundedBox(latlong1, latlong2, latlong3)
{
    var betweenLats;
    var betweenLons;

    if(latlong1.Latitude < latlong2.Latitude)
        betweenLats = (latlong1.Latitude <= latlong3.Latitude && 
latlong2.Latitude >= latlong3.Latitude);
    else
        betweenLats = (latlong1.Latitude >= latlong3.Latitude && 
latlong2.Latitude <= latlong3.Latitude);

    if(latlong1.Longitude < latlong2.Longitude)
        betweenLons = (latlong1.Longitude <= latlong3.Longitude && 
latlong2.Longitude >= latlong3.Longitude);
    else
        betweenLons = (latlong1.Longitude >= latlong3.Longitude && 
latlong2.Longitude <= latlong3.Longitude);

    return (betweenLats && betweenLons);
}
```

However, when I was testing this algorithm with these two polygons, Checking on google maps `polygon 1` contains `polygon 2`. But the algorithm is returning false, i.e. these polygons do not overlap. Please suggest how to fix this.

```
Polygon 1:
————–+——————+——————+
| polygon_id | latitude | longitude |
+————–+——————+——————+
| 158 | 13.1303042583903 | 77.7543640136719 |
| 158 | 13.1420061213258 | 77.6383209228516 |
| 158 | 13.1189362005413 | 77.5209045410156 |
| 158 | 12.9209143604345 | 77.3890686035156 |
| 158 | 12.7970707734707 | 77.4900054931641 |
| 158 | 12.8446071570180 | 77.6403808593750 |
| 158 | 12.8499628062145 | 77.8154754638672 |
| 158 | 12.9436681426755 | 77.8504943847656 |
| 158 | 13.0420208479226 | 77.8154754638672



 Polygon 2:        
    +--------------+------------------+------------------+
| polygon_id | latitude         | longitude        |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
|          150 | 12.8969871916682 | 77.5722312927246 |
|          150 | 12.9225875033164 | 77.6108551025391 |
|          150 | 12.8817596199286 | 77.6197814941406 |
|          150 | 12.8887878450392 | 77.5693130493164 |
+--------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: According to [this comment](https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/determine-if-two-polygons-overlap/#comment-2551) by the author of the blog post it doesn't work if one polygon completely contains the other. The lines have to overlap.

Comment: @samgak the comment is `The algorithm will determine if a polygon intersects (overlaps) or is complete contained. However it won’t just tell you if is complete contains and not overlapping. The algorithm could be easily changed though to determine that.`  This comment suggest that , it will determine if polygon intersect.

Comment: In your example, you put twice the same polygon, is it normal ?

Comment: @DamienProt thanks for pointing out. I have updated the example.

Comment: @Jagrati, the second line of the comment says `it won’t just tell you if is complete contains and not overlapping`. Your testing seems to confirm that. Although, the comment seems to contradict itself.

Comment: `it won’t just tell you if is complete contains and not overlapping` I think it means that it will just return true or false, will not give any information regarding if polygons overlap or are contained.

Answer (score 0):

The part about the intersection looks correct to me, but I don't think it is possible to assert that a polygon is included into another polygon so easily. In fact, if we look more carefully at the code, the algorithm is able to say if polygon A is included into polygon B by only looking at a segment of A and a segment of B. It means that, without knowing anything else about the polygons, giving one segment of each polygon is enough to know if these polygons are included one into the other. That is clearly wrong.

Comment: I don't understand, the in this algorithm after finding the intersection, we check if the intersect is bounded within two lat lngs.